# JavaScript regular expression for time formatting for saving space

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help for regular expression that can do below;

08:30a  desired output  8:30a
08:00p  desired output  8p
02:45a  desired output  2:45a
10:05a  desired output  10:05a
12:53p  desired output  12:53p

Thanks for help

Comment: -1 What have you tried?  Maybe you could also put a little more effort into asking your question clearly.

Comment: Why do you think a regular expression is the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're after  -

```
 # Find:  /(?:[0]([1-9])|([1][0-2]))(?:(?::00|(:[0][1-9]))|(:[1-5][0-9]))([aApP])[mM]?/
 # Replace:  $1$2$3$4$5

 (?:
      [0] 
      ( [1-9] )                # (1)
   |  
      ( [1] [0-2] )            # (2)
 )
 (?:
      (?:
           : 00 
        |  
           ( : [0] [1-9] )     # (3)
      )
   |  
      ( : [1-5] [0-9] )        # (4)
 )
 ( [aApP] )                    # (5)
 [mM]?
```

Perl test case

```
$/ = undef;

$str = <DATA>;

$str =~ s/(?:[0]([1-9])|([1][0-2]))(?:(?::00|(:[0][1-9]))|(:[1-5][0-9]))([aApP])[mM]?/$1$2$3$4$5/g;

print "$str\n";


__DATA__

08:30a desired output 8:30a
08:00p desired output 8p
02:45a desired output 2:45a
10:05a desired output 10:05a
12:53p desired output 12:53p
```

Output >>

```
8:30a desired output 8:30a
8p desired output 8p
2:45a desired output 2:45a
10:05a desired output 10:05a
12:53p desired output 12:53p
```